# How big is the World of Warcraft in real world geographic terms?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Let's specify this question<sup>[a]</sup> a bit:

I'm not interested in how big the [continents or whole world](http://www.wowwiki.com/index.php?title=Travel_guide&image=World-of-warcraft-cataclysm-boat-zeppelin-route-map-jpg) are *supposed* to be, but rather in an approximation (or measurements) how big all the zones<sup>[b]</sup> combined are on all the continents together.

That is, **map size in km² / mi² / real world comparison** when comparing the zone sizes with the avatars size and how long it takes one to run through.

I would appreciate answers that are backed up by some research. Educated guesses are welcome too, but please try to motivate how you arrived at your guesses. :-) Thanks!

<sub>[a]: Note that I "stole" this question title from a question [here](http://www.mahalo.com/answers/how-big-are-virtual-worlds-like-everquestworld-of-warcraft-in-real-world-geographic-terms), and I found another random q [here](http://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090919225745AAndNqC) that doesn't give a satisfying answer either.</sub>

<sub>[b]: I never played that much. Are they called "[zones](http://www.wowwiki.com/Azeroth_%28continent%29#Zones)"? If not, feel free to edit.</sub>

Comment: Not a truly satisfying answer either, but great fun to watch (note it's nearly 3 years old, so about the time TBC came out) http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/video/2008/jun/25/interesting.world.warcraft

Comment: Probably should link this one in: http://mapwow.com/

Comment: And another measurement: http://www.ytrilynth.org/board/viewtopic.php?t=282

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Great question :)

I wondered it myself and googled it before trying, so here is a good discussion on the issue;

http://tobolds.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-big-is-azeroth.html

And a mentionable and scientific! approach in a comment :)

Mages can use "blink" to jump forward 20 yards. So, I blinked forward five times, ran back and measured the distance a few times. 
Averaging it out, you run 100 yards in 14.15 seconds.
100yards / 14.15 seconds = 7.067 yards/sec
Three yards to a foot, means 21.201 feet/sec.
Which works out to 14.46 MPH.
Meaning, in 18 minutes 35 second you actually ran 4.48 Miles.
So, lastly, 4.48 miles / 3.7 * (6.4 miles on each side [The square root of 41 square miles]) = 7.75 Miles on one side.
7.75² = Kalimdor is closer to 60.1 Square Miles

For ref: Manhattan is 20 square miles

read all the comments, they made quite a discussion on the issue..